Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:1) with shape [1, 10] to a Java object with shape [1, 9]
I trained a tflite object detection model with a custom dataset in google colab and tried to deploy it into flutter app project. Then this error occured:
E/AndroidRuntime(13887): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:1) with shape [1, 10] to a Java object with shape [1, 9].
I asked chat gpt and copilot and they offered this solution:
if (detector != null) {
      // Check if the shape of the tensor matches the expected shape
      if (detector[0]['detectedClass'].length == 10) {
        // Copy the first 9 elements to reshape the tensor to [1, 9]
        List<String> reshapedList = List<String>.from(detector[0]['detectedClass'].take(9));
        // Ensure the reshaped list has exactly 9 elements
        while (reshapedList.length < 9) {
          reshapedList.add(''); // Add empty strings to fill any missing elements
        }
        detector[0]['detectedClass'] = reshapedList;
      }
      // Update controller.label with information about the detected object
      String detectedLabel = detector[0]['detectedClass'].join(", "); // Join the elements to form a string
      double confidence = detector[0]['confidence'];
      // Construct a label string with class and confidence
      label = '$detectedLabel (${(confidence * 100).toStringAsFixed(2)}%)';
      // Extract and log specific information from detector if needed
      log("Result is $detector");
    } else {
      // No object detected
      label = 'No object detected';
    }

However, the same error is still emerging
